# Lombok @NonNull annotation with @Builder not reflecting in test coverage

Tags: java, lombok, builder-pattern

I have come across an issue while testing **lombok** annotated class.
Description :-

When we annotate a java class(POJO) with `@Builder`, and have certain instance variable with `@NonNull` constraints, while writing the test case to check for `NullPointerException`, we cannot instantiate the **POJO** with builder and expect it will evaluate against the null check.I delomboked the class and saw that the non null constraint flows inside the generated builder class itself which means a null pointer exception is thrown even before we construct the object.This is a correct behavior in some sense but I needed to know if I can test such a scenario.

```
@Builder
public class Sample {
    @NonNull
    private final String a;
    private final String b;
}
```

Now I need to test the case where NullPointerException is thrown in case 'a' is Null.
For such a scenario I have 2 options:

- Either I can create the Sample class with constructor - `new Sample(null, null)`
- Or I can create through builder - `Sample.builder.a(null).build();`

My question is on the second part as first one will work just fine.
When I delombok this I will get something like :-

```
public class Sample {
    @NonNull
    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    Sample(@NonNull String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static SampleBuilder builder() {
        return new SampleBuilder();
    }

    public static class SampleBuilder {
        private @NonNull String a;
        private String b;

        SampleBuilder() {
        }

        public SampleBuilder a(@NonNull String a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this;
        }

        public SampleBuilder b(String b) {
            this.b = b;
            return this;
        }

        public Sample build() {
            return new Sample(a, b);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Sample.SampleBuilder(a=" + this.a + ", b=" + this.b + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Here if you see NullPointerException will be thrown inside SampleBuilder itself as it takes `@NonNull` arguments and constructor will never execute the condition to check for non null attribute due to which test coverage will fall.If we use `@SuperBuilder` , this will not happen as it does not take `@NonNull` in builder arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code we can see that if we want to trigger NPE at constructor level we need to leave the @NonNull parameter as empty rather than setting it to null which will trigger builder method level NPE.
If I build Sample object in the following manner it should suffice my case:-

```
Sample sample = Sample.builder.b("b").build();
```

Here I am not explicitly setting parameter 'a' to NULL if I want to test NPE of 'a' at constructor level.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are expecting, but the source code below can properly test the `null` check of both constructor and builder of Sample class.

You can see it running at https://repl.it/repls/CleverWiryTruespace.

```
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Builder;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

class Main {
  @Builder
  public static class Sample {
      @NonNull
      private final String a;
      private final String b;
  }

  public static class TestSample {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
      thrown.expect(NullPointerException.class);
      thrown.expectMessage("a is marked non-null but is null");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
      Sample s = new Sample(null, "abc");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
      Sample.builder().a(null).build();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JUnitCore().main(TestSample.class.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me clarify with your test case example itself.What I wanted to achieve is to get NullPointerException at the constrcutor level by creating object through builder.

Comment: In the above example you mentioned (test2), NullPointerException will be thrown but at the SampleBuilder method level which means I cannot cover lombok generated branch coverage line for @NonNull constructor arguments which says something like if (a==null), throw NPE.I can achieve this by not setting parameter 'a' at all.I can write test2(), in the following manner - Sample.builder().build(); This will not trigger NPE at builder level but at the constructor level.

Comment: Yes, and that's totally expected, since is not a concern of the builder pattern. It is not intended to do a pre-validation when build is invoked. That would be redundant. Also, the builder pattern will invoke a constructor, that can even have additional constraints.

Comment: I think you might be trying to get 100% coverage, but this is incorrect. You should filter those lombok generated methods out of your coverage. 100% coverage should mean covering 100% of YOUR CODE, not something that has been generated by a third party library. You need to trust code provided by external dependencies.